# Converting a character dataframe column to fractional time

Tags: r, time, apply

I have a dataframe with a column containing time values in the "HH:MM:SS" format. I have written a function to convert this to fractional values

```
convertTime = function(ttime){
  ttime2 =strsplit(ttime,":")
  h = as.numeric(ttime2[[1]][1])
  m = as.numeric(ttime2[[1]][2])
  hh = h + m/60
  return(hh/24)
}

convertTime("11:30:00")
```

> [1] 0.4791667

This works fine. However when I attempt to apply this to a whole column I receive an error:

```
data = data.frame(c("17:30:00", "13:00:00", "19:30:00"))
colnames(data) = c("timeString")
decimalTime = apply(data$timeString, 2, convertTime)
```

> Error in apply(dat$gameTime, 2, convertTime) : 
>         dim(X) must have a positive length

Perhaps I am not correctly using the apply function. In anycase, if you could point out what I'm doing wrong, I'd be grateful!

Comment: This could also be vectorised using R's datetime functions: `xp <- as.POSIXlt(x, format="%H:%M:%S", tz="UTC");
difftime(xp, trunc(xp, units="days"), units="days")` where `x` is your character vector of times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the function, we can loop through the elements and then apply

```
sapply(as.character(data$timeString), convertTime)
#  17:30:00  13:00:00  19:30:00 
#0.7291667 0.5416667 0.8125000
```

Instead of doing the `sapply` loop outside the function, the function can be changed

```
convertTime2 <- function(ttime) {
  ttime2 <- strsplit(ttime,":")
   sapply(ttime2, function(x) {x1 <- as.numeric(x)
             (x1[1] + x1[2]/60)/24
              })
 }

convertTime2("11:30:00")
#[1] 0.4791667
convertTime2(as.character(data$timeString))
#[1] 0.7291667 0.5416667 0.8125000
```

---

The `apply` will not work because `data$timeString` is a `vector` or column of dataset and `apply` needs a dimensional object i.e. either `matrix` or `data.frame`.

Comment: Thank you! Clear explanation and great solution.